# Hibernate: Calling a PLSQL procedure for each connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to call a PLSQL procedure for each connection that hibernates generates for me.
The background is, that our database server only allows operations with sessions which are already initialized by a certain PLSQL call.

So my questition is, where can I register me to listen to new connections and call the procedure on the server.

Regards, Johannes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get better answers, please provide information about which technology you're using to create your data sources for Hibernate. For example, Tomcat's data source configuration allows for this using initSQL: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Tomcat_JDBC_Enhanced_Attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inject SessionFactory, use .getCurrentSession(), if you create and manage SessionManager yourself - user .createSession()(i believe it's called so?). Then use .createNativeQuery() and execute() to make procedure call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser. I forget to mention, that I'm on a server in a JPA environment. So I have only something like Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "db" ) and entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(). Any ideas for this environment?

Comment: `EntityManagerFactory emFactory  = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db");`//'db' name here must be in persistence.xml also
//then instead of .createSession() this:
`EntityManager manager = emFactory.createEntityManager();`

working with EntityManager is a little different than with Session, use javadoc. However, this is for manual control over managers: you'll have to   `manager.close();` after all done.